# How to convert from one's complement to two's complement

Tags: twos-complement

I am confused on how to do conversion from one's complement to two's complement.
Suppose we have 10101101 in one's complement. How to convert it to two's complement?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just look at the definitions:

*One's complement* means that the bits in the negation of the value are complement (inversion) of all the bits in the original.

*Two's complement* of an N-bit number is defined as the result of subtracting the original N-bit number from 2^N. The effect of this operation has the same result on the original number as taking the one's complement and adding 1.

In this case then, if `10101101` is the one's complement, just add one to get the two's complement, which would be `10101110`. Or, doing it the long way:

1. One's complement = `10101101`
2. Original number = `01010010` (invert the bits per definition of one's complement)
3. Two's complement = `2^8 - 01010010` = `100000000 - 01010010` = `10101110`

Comment: Okay, thanks... Then, if we want to get from two's complement negative number to binary representation. How would we do that? 
Would we substract one?

Comment: @FemX get to binary representation of what? The original, unnegated number? If you have a 2's complement and want to negate it back to he original, you would reverse the operation: subtract 1, then take the complement (NOTE: "complement" is its own identity inverse, so complement of the complement of X is the original X).

Comment: @FemX, if you have a 2's complement and you want the 1's complement, yes, you would just subtract 1.